# Is there a specific getting started guide for the M5StickCPlus?

Tags: nanoframework

Is there a specific getting started guide for the M5StickCPlus? I have attempted to adapt some samples from the samples repo, in particular [Blinky](https://github.com/nanoframework/Samples/blob/main/samples/Blinky/Blinky/Program.cs).

I have tried several variations, but I cannot access the LED; I get an exception

```
    ++++ Exception System.NullReferenceException - CLR_E_NULL_REFERENCE (8) ++++
    ++++ Message: 
    ++++ nanoFramework.M5Stack.M5StickCPlus::get_Led [IP: 000e] ++++
    ++++ Exception System.NullReferenceException - CLR_E_NULL_REFERENCE (9) ++++
    ++++ Message: 
    ++++ nanoFramework.M5Stack.M5StickCPlus::get_Led [IP: 000e] ++++
```

```cs
    public class Program
    { 
        public static void Main()
        {
            M5StickCPlus.Led.Write(PinValue.Low);
        }
    }
```

```cs
    public class Program
    { 
        private static GpioController gpio = new GpioController();
        public static void Main()
        {
            gpio.OpenPin(M5StickCPlus.Led.PinNumber);
            M5StickCPlus.Led.Write(PinValue.Low);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looked at the code briefly and it seems there's a missing init for GpioController in the constructor. Please raise an issue for this on nanoFramework github home repo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - if you do anything to get the internal GPIO object first you can then use the LED object.

```
Debug.WriteLine($"{M5StickCPlus.GpioController.IsPinOpen(10)}");
M5StickCPlus.Led.Toggle();
```